# PC only boot the “Choose an option” Screen

Tags: windows-10, bootloader

Problem: Windows boot to "Choose an option" Screen with the options: 
1. Continue - Exit and continue to windows 
2. Use a device 
3. TroubleShoot 
4. Turn off your PC

I performed a clean windows 10 installation, but the PC still boots to the same screen. - When selecting option "1. Exit and continue to windows" it loops back to the same screen.

None of the repair option the troubleshoot section help, PC always loops back to "Choose an option".

However when accessing the boot menu "pressing Ese, then F9" and selecting the internal Hard disk, windows boots fine, but when restarted it goes back to "Choose an option" screen.

Options i've tried:
- Clean Boot
- Repair & Reset (From Recover Media: UBS Drive)
- Chkdsk in CMD
- Bootrex / rebuild, and other options, in CMD
- sfc / scannow in CMD
- Hard drive Diagnoses (BIOS, F2 option)

Please advice on how I can stop windows from booting the "Choose an option" and boot straight to windows 10.

Comment: Have you removed the installation media?

Comment: Install media has nothing to do with it.  @Dray A. Leo If the below works, I'll put it in an answer. Two things: You're not using an answer file for the install are you? | and | Windows 10 must be allowed to fully boot to the Desktop once the install begins. Do not turn off the PC before it boots to the desktop, which is after it finalizes OOBE.  If the 1st answer is no & the 2nd is Windows did, try what I suggest below.  Please note, the `clean` command in `DiskPart` will wipe the HDD's partition table, so if you have data on it you need, let me know and I'll give a different set of commands

Comment: @Dray A. Leo It sounds like either the Windows bootloader is missing or there's no BCD entry for the install, both of which are odd if you clean installed. Boot up install media & once it loads, press Shift+F10. Issue: `bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd` (select yes if it finds an OS)., and reboot. If issue persists, its going to be easier to simply re-install, but perform the following first in a terminal (Shift+F10) - issue: `diskpart`, `lis dis`, (select HDD to install to) `sel dis #`, (this will erase all partitions) `clean`

Comment: Set first boot device in the bios to the hard drive you installed windows on.

Comment: @Moab It's impossible to get the WinRE page Dray A. Leo is receiving by leaving the install media in or by having the install media's boot device listed over that of the HDD.  As I stated above, this has nothing to do with the install media.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I had performed those process before, however when executing "bootrec /fixboot" the system responds "Access denied". 
. . . . . . .
I Did the "diskpart clean and diskpart / convert GPT" to proform clean installation twice, however, the problem persists, 
. . . . . . .
Boot Options are as Follow in the Bios . . . 
1 OS Boot Manager  |   2 Internal CD/DVD  |    3 USB Disk  |  4 USB CD/?DVD   |   5 Network Adapter . . . Installation media is not plugged into the system